# Token Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, token, bearer-token

security token after logging in / registering with Java

I would like to know how it is possible to create a security token after logging in / registering with Java spring boot (v3 of spring boot).

Make also the example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a side server interceptor to authenticate and set the user header on the connect message by the following code:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MyConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
            StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                    MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
            if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                Authentication user = ... ; // access authentication header(s)
                accessor.setUser(user);
            }
            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that I have implemented in my application:

The security filter chain that is applied to every request:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

    // interceptor
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("securityFilterChain implemented");

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(
                        httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/api/v1/auth/logout")
                                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())
                );

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

The UserInfoUserDetailsService (* in import means the path that you will have in your code):

```
import *.repository.UserRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserInfoUserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepo.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

The JWT service:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class JwtService {

    private final String secreteKey = "7272e597ccdf234969df0e46c28cae10d482afcd942eea4aa00e1c86b38dd84f";
    private static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 60000 * 15; //15 min

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }


    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails);
    }


    private String buildToken(
            Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
            UserDetails userDetails
    ) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + EXPIRATION_TIME);
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        final boolean checkTokenValid = username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token);
        log.info("Token is valid: " + checkTokenValid);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final boolean checkTokenExpired = extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
        log.info("isTokenExpired: " + checkTokenExpired);
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(secreteKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

The JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("Doing the doFilterInternal method");
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userEmail;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.split(" ")[1].trim();
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        log.info("jwt: " + jwt + " and userEmail: " + userEmail);
        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                log.info(authToken + " this is the authToken");
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The User Model:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

//@Data
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id != null && Objects.equals(id, user.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The User Repository:

```
import *.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

The User Service:

i

```
mport *.config.JwtService;
import *.dto.AuthenticationRequest; //you can provide a DTO which is a object that can be mapped as JSON for the requests
import *.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import *.dto.RegisterRequest;
import *.model.Role; // enum type
import *.model.User;
import *.repository.UserRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserService {


    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


    public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        log.info("Authenticating the user...");
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                )
        );
        User user = userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        Role role = user.getRole();
        Map<String, Object> extraClaims = new HashMap<>();
        extraClaims.put("role", role);
        String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(extraClaims, user);
        return AuthenticationResponse.builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .build();
    }
// an example of how you can register an user; You can also add the logic for the token generation
    public void register(RegisterRequest request) {
        log.info("Registering the user...");
        User user = User.builder()
                .username(request.getUsername())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
                .role(request.getRole())
                .build();
        userRepo.save(user);

    }
}
```

The User Rest Controller:

```
import *.dto.AuthenticationRequest;
import *.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import *.model.User;
import *.repository.UserRepo;
import *.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserController {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
// authenticate user with the credentials
    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.authenticate(request));
    }
//register user with credentials
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterRequest user) {
        userService.register(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User added");
    }
}
```

**Note** that this is an implementation that uses Spring JPA (assuming that you have users stored in database).

Basically, I configured a security filter chain that ensure that every request is validated (this also includes the checking of authentication and JWT token). Then, I implemented the logic of JWT Token generation and validation. Finally, I made a User Rest Controller (using Controller, Service, Repository architecture) that performs the login and register processes.

PS: You can use this repo as reference/tutorial: https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-3-jwt-security/tree/main/src/main/java/com/alibou/security
Also, you can look up to Amigoscode on Youtube on this specific topic. He explains very well how you can implement the token security using Spring Security module and the logic behind it.
I hope this helps.